# Non-trivial equivalence relation on $\{1, ..., n\}$ invariant under a simple transitive subgroup of $S_n$

Tags: group-theory, permutations, equivalence-relations

Let $G$ be a **simple**, **transitive** subgroup of $S_n$ (meaning that the action of $G$ on $\{1, ...,n\}$ is transitive). Let $\sim$ be a given equivalence relation on the set $\{1,...,n\}$ satisfying the following property: for any $\sigma \in G$,

$$i\sim j \implies \sigma(i)\sim \sigma(j).\tag{$*$}$$

**Question**: What can we conclude about $\sim$?

**Discussion**: Obviously we can have the trivial relation. Given a non-trivial $\sim$, I suspect we must have $i\sim j$ for any $i, j\in \{1,...,n\}$.

One can check that $(*)$ implies any $\sigma \in G$ takes an equivalence class $[i]$ to the equivalence class $[\sigma(i)]$. As a consequence all equivalence classes under $\sim$ are of the same size $k>1$. I can construct a homomorphism $G\to S_{n/k}$ by looking at how each $\sigma$ permutes the set of equivalence classes. The kernel of this map is either trivial or all of $G$. In the second case the transitivity of $G$ would imply $n=k$ the desired result.

I am having trouble dealing with the first case. I don't see a problem with $G$ being a subgroup of $S_{n/k}$ where $k>1$. Am I missing something? or is the claim mistaken in the first place?

Note: This question is based on problem 6.5.11 in Berkeley Problem Books in Mathematics.

**Edit**: Per Derek Holt's answer the claim is indeed incorrect. We know that it is possible to have block size $1<k<n$. What more can we say about this equivalence relation? A question that come to mind is:

- If we are given $k|n$, can we construct a simple transitive subgroup $G\subseteq S_n$ such that there is an equivalence relation $\sim$ with block size $k$?

Comment: Sorry, the previous comment was mistaken. The example wouldn't work because $G$ has a normal subgroup of index $2$, where $G$ is required to be simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalence classes form a system of blocks of *imprimitivity* preserved by $G$. The group is called *primitive* if the only such equivalent relations are the two obvious ones, where the blocks are either singletons of the whole set.

If you are looking for examples, $A_5$ arises as an imprimitive subgroup of $S_{12}$ with blocks of size $2$, with the action on the cosets of a subgroup of order $5$.

More generally, the action of a group $G$ on the cosets of any proper non-maximal subgroup is imprimitive. More precisely, If $|G:H| = n$ and there is a subgroup $K$ with $H < K < G$ and $|K:H|=k$, then there is an imprimitive action of $G$ of degree $n$ with blocks of size $k$.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your example. How can we inject $A_5$ into $S_{10}$ such that the image is transitive?

Comment: Sorry, make that $S_{12}$! (There is an embedding of $A_5$ as a transitive subgroup of $S_{10}$ arising from the action on the cosets of $S_3 < A_{5}$ , but that group is primitive.)

Comment: Ahhh I see! The block of size two are given by the two cosets of $\mathbb{Z}_5$ in $D_5$, and $A_5$ preserves the cosets of $D_5$ hence the 2-blocks as well. I suppose this is why maximality of the subgroup matters.

Comment: Thank you for the counter-example! Can we say more about the case when $G$ is imprimitive? It feels like the requirements of $G$ being simple should be very restrictive.

Comment: I have added a little more detail about imprimitive actions in general, but all of it refers to arbitrary groups $G$. I am not aware of anything extra that you can say when $G$ is simple, although of course that will significantly restrict the values of $k$ and $n$ that can arise.